# How to embed Office documents stored in SharePoint in other web applications

Tags: sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013

With Microsoft introducing Office Web Apps it has made it easy for us to embed office documents in our custom web applications that will use the Office Web App to render the document. In order to generate the embed code there is an option of "Embed" in Sky drive as shown here: http://office.microsoft.com/en-au/web-apps-help/share-it-embed-an-excel-workbook-on-your-blog-HA102029502.aspx

There are Office Web apps available for SharePoint 2010 and SharePoint 2013 this allows me to surface office documents within SharePoint using the Office Web app. What I want to do is use SharePoint as my document repository and be able to embed documents that are stored on the SharePoint server in my custom web application the same way I can do it for documents stored on the Sky Drive. There is any option in SharePoint to view the document in the browser but I cannot copy that link and add it to a web page on my application at it shows the actual SharePoint site.

All I want to do is use the Office Web App deployed on the SharePoint server to render documents that are stored on the same SharePoint server within an iFrame.

Wanted to find out if this is possible at all if so how do I achieve this on my SharePoint server 2010 or 2013 but would prefer to do this on 2010.

Comment: Have you tried? It seems like it'd be easy to test with a page viewer web part.

Comment: @Manthan - any progress on this? I just installed SP2013, and I am finding the same thing. I am able to access the embed code for word and ppt docs, but not excel docs. I just want it to work the same way that SkyDrive does.